Create a bash script with multiple arguments using getopts
I want to create a bash script that accepts some arguments and has the following usage:
$ ./execute.sh add person --id 123 --name John

I found getopts and was trying to use it to parse the options but without success. My current code is:
#!/bin/bash

command=$1
entity=$2

while getopts ":id:name:" opt; do
  echo "opt: ${opt}"
  case ${opt} in
  id)
    id=$OPTARG
    ;;
  name)
    name=$OPTARG
    ;;
  \?)
    echo "Invalid option: $OPTARG" 1>&2
    ;;
  :)
    echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." 1>&2
    ;;
  esac
done

if [ -z "${id}" ] || [ -z "${name}" ]; then
  echo "Missing required options" 1>&2
  echo "Usage: $0 <command> <entity> --id <number> --name <string>"
  exit 1
fi

case $command in
add)
  echo "adding entity $entity..."
  ;;
*)
  echo "invalid command: $command"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac


But with that, the output I have is:
Missing required options
Usage: ./execute.sh <command> <entity> --id <number> --name <string>

So, it seems that it's not parsing the options at all, but I'm not sure why.
Any help and tips appreciated.

getopts does not support long options like --id so if you want those it makes more sense to write your own option parsing.
